# ggplot: keep circle looking round when aspect ratio != 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to plot a round circle and it gets stretched

```
library(tidyverse)

n = 100
radius = 1
circle <- tibble(x = accumulate(1:(n-1), ~ radius*cos(.y*2*pi/n), .init = radius),
                 y = accumulate(1:(n-1), ~ radius*sin(.y*2*pi/n), .init = 0))

ggplot(circle) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y), color = "red")
```

[image]
I can use coord_equal()

```
ggplot(circle) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y), color = "red") +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]
But I want to maintain the default (3/4) aspect ratio, specifically when saving I do not want the graphic device to add padding on the sides.

Please advise

Comment: If you want the circle to be a circle, and maintain a 3/4 aspect ratio, you'll need padding. How exactly do you want the plot to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide the `limits`  argument of the position scales as a function that takes the natural limits of the data as the argument. This works with a fixed aspect ratio, but doesn't automatically adapt to fit the available size in the graphics device.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n = 100
radius = 1
circle <- tibble(x = accumulate(1:(n-1), ~ radius*cos(.y*2*pi/n), .init = radius),
                 y = accumulate(1:(n-1), ~ radius*sin(.y*2*pi/n), .init = 0))

asp <- 3 / 4

ggplot(circle) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y), color = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = function(x) {
      mid <- mean(x)
      mid + c(-1, 1) * (1/asp) * 0.5 * diff(x)
    }
  ) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>